# If statement in a js

Tags: javascript

First of all. Hello everyone, I'm starting to learn how to use `js` now and I have a question.

So I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});



//Getting from property_page1.json
$(".pagination li.page").on("click", function(){
var attr=$(this).attr('rel');
    var tableRow="";
    $.getJSON("property_page" + attr + ".json" , function(data){
        $.each(data.data, function(index, test){
            tableRow  += "<tr class='table-row'>"+"<td>"+test.title+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+test.is_favorite+"</td>"+"<td>"
                +test.city+"</td>"+"<td>"+test.amenities+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+test.verbose_price+"</td>"+"<td>"
                +"<img src = '"+test.images_url[0].url+"'height= '120' width= '350'>"
                +"</td>"
                +"<td>"+test.is_favorite+"</td>"+"</tr>"
            });
                $("#userdata tbody").html(tableRow);
        });
    });
    //End
});
```

So I wanna know how I can add an If statement in the table part. Instead of `test.is_favorite` to make a statement that shows me that if the value is `true` it displays `Yes` and if it's false it displays `No`.

I know it's a stupid question but I'm still learning.

Comment: Have a look at - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1):

using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is the quick/simple way:

```
 +"<td>"+ (test.is_favorite === true ? 'Yes' : 'No') +"</td>"+"</tr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should probably use the ternary operator.
If you don't know it, this is how to use it : `condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`

So in your case : `(test.is_favorite ? 'Yes' : 'No')`. I added parentheses to prevent any confusion :-)

Bonus : [javascript.info](http://javascript.info) is a website that helped me a lot when learning JavaScript. However, it won't teach you how to use jQuery ;-)

Comment: I used the ternary operator and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use try the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});



//Getting from property_page1.json
$(".pagination li.page").on("click", function(){
var attr=$(this).attr('rel');
    var tableRow="";
    $.getJSON("property_page" + attr + ".json" , function(data){
        $.each(data.data, function(index, test){
        
           var show_str = "";
           if(test.is_favorite){
              show_str+="Yes";
           }else{
              show_str+="No";
           }
        
            tableRow  += "<tr class='table-row'>"+"<td>"+test.title+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+show_str+"</td>"+"<td>"
                +test.city+"</td>"+"<td>"+test.amenities+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+test.verbose_price+"</td>"+"<td>"
                +"<img src = '"+test.images_url[0].url+"'height= '120' width= '350'>"
                +"</td>"
                +"<td>"+show_str+"</td>"+"</tr>"
            });
                $("#userdata tbody").html(tableRow);
    });
});
//End
});
```